# Reference a Contact field as a value in a Task Process with Process Builder

Tags: process-builder, formula-field, tasks

- I need to update 3 fields on Task based on the values from the possible related objects (Lead or Contact) using the standard "Related To" field.
- I need to do this without code.

I was thinking of using Process Builder- for criteria `LEFT([Task].WhoId, 3) = '003'` and for actions.

I am unable to reference the required field from contacts, I tried `Contact.Account_Industry` but I receive the error:

> The formula expression is invalid: Field Contact.Account_Industry does not exist. Check spelling.

And the field really exists on the Contact object as a formula field referencing the Account.

Am I missing something?

Comment: `Contact.Account_Industry` is formula field on contact? so ur PB is trying to assign value for this field?

Comment: Contact.Account_Industry is a formula field on Contact. My PB is trying to get it's value and update a field on the Task called Industry.

Comment: Task.RelatedTo is a polymorphic relationship - [this Automation Champion blog might help](https://automationchampion.com/2017/07/31/getting-started-with-process-builder-part-76-working-with-polymorphic-relationship/#more-10133)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access to the related contact information from task object with formula, validation rules or process builder. This field reference this information on task is polymorphic so it can contain several lead or contact.

There is an idea concerning your requirement : https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kduDAAQ

So unfortunately the only way to meet your need is to use a trigger.